# How to call SAML (http-post binding) based REST APIs using Angular?

Tags: java, angular, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have OData REST APIs protected with SAML 2.0(POST binding) and I have Angular 2+ client application. How can I call these REST APIs using Angular application?

When I use Angular HTTP client 
`import {Http, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';`

I'm getting form with continue button to ***Note:Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the Continue button once to proceed.***

If I hit same REST API URL directly in browser, then browser redirects to IDP and then, after successful authentication,  IdP redirects back it to REST API.

The same behavior is observed on Postman, but they are fixing it by enabling JS script preview.

Here is Angular code which i tried:

```
this.POST('https://<RESTAppfqdn>/odata', {"ID": "2"}).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data)
})
}

POST(url, data) {
const headers = Object.assign({
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
Accept: 'application/json;vnd.ptc.ilm.webui2.0=true;text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
});
var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
method: RequestMethod.Post,
url: url,
headers: headers,
body: data
})

return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
.pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
```

Here is response I can see in browser's network tab:

````
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        </head>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
                you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
            </p>
        </noscript>

        <form action="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;<Idpfqn>&#x3a;9031&#x2f;idp&#x2f;SSO.saml2" method="post">
            <div>

                <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="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"/>                

            </div>
            <noscript>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
                </div>
            </noscript>
        </form>
            </body>
</html>```

As Angular http client reside  in browser, browser should take care of handling this post form submission and redirection work but that is not happening. Is there any way by which i can tell browser to handle such responses?
````

Comment: Angular 2+ is written in TypeScript. I is not an AngularJS (JS stands for JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

As there is form in response received from server, I have submit that form. 
Hence, I have created a div (ex. auth) in index.html and when the response contains the form then submit that. Here is that code.

```
if (res['error']['text']) {
 let authDiv = document.getElementById('auth') 
 authDiv.innerHTML = res['error']['text'] 
 var f1 = authDiv.children[1] 
 f1.submit() 
 return new HttpResponseFailAction([res['error']['text']]) 
}
```

But then we will face another issues with that:

Ex. The auth challenge received from IdP has to be displayed.

Basically, we need to act like browser and any coming requests we need to handle.

Hence, I decided to discarded this approach and added SAML SSO support to client application itself.

Comment: Hi,
Did u send the POST request from the web app itself ?

Comment: @Kishor Jadhav  Can you help us, we are facing same issue. In Network tab we can see SAML Response how to consume same in Angular 8